# Neo4J CYPHER Query to make relation

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have 2 Types of nodes
Type 1- Country with country Code
Type 2- Language with country code

I need to make language spoken in country Relationship
[language]-[:SPOKEN_IN]->[Country]

I am a beginner for Cypher
I Tried

```
CREATE (a:language)-[:TALK_IN]->(b:country) WHERE a.CountryCode = b.Code
```

But It didn't worked
How to achieve this relation?

Comment: The attribute names are case sensitive . Same applicable to label names and relationshiptypes. Make sure you are using correct attribute names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following query:

```
MATCH (c:COUNTRY), (l:LANGUAGE) WHERE c.code = l.countryCode CREATE (l)-[:TALK_IN]->(c)
```

- MATCH finds all nodes labeled with COUNTRY and LANGUAGE
- WHERE makes sure their country codes match
- CREATE creates the TALK_IN relationship